# how to disable Google Translate API from not translating proper names with common words

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-translator-toolkit

I am using Google Cloud Platform to create content in Indian regional language. Some of the content contains buildings and society name which have common words like 'The Nest Glory'. After conversion from Google Translate API the building name should only be spelled in the regional language, instead it is literally being translated. It sounds funny and user will never find that building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Translation API can be told not to translate some part of the text, use the following HTML tags:

```
<span translate="no"> </span>
<span class="notranslate"> </span>
```

This functionality requires the source text to be submitted in HTML.

[Access to the Cloud Translation API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions)

[How to Disable Google Translate from Translating Specific Words](https://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-disable-google-translate-from-translating-specific-words-or-content-blocks/)

Comment: Excuse for the (maybe) trivial question, how can I "submit text in HTML"?

Answer (score 1):

After some search I think one older way is to use the transliteration API which was deprecated by google

[Google Transliteration API Deprecated](https://developers.google.com/transliterate/v1/getting_started)

Answer (score 0):

```
translate="no"
class="notranslate"
```

in last API versions this features doesn't work

That's a very complex thing to do: it needs semantic analysis as well as translation and there is no real way to simply add that to your application. The best we can suggest is that you identify the names, remove them from the strings (or replace them with non-translated markers as the may not be in anything like the same position in translated messages) and re-instate them afterwards.
But ... that may well change the quality of the translation; as I said, Google Translate is pretty clever ... but it isn't at Human Interpreter yet.

If that doesn't work, you need to use a real-world human translator who is very familiar with the source and target languages.